# is just saying $p$ equivalent to saying $p$ is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In my textbook *modus ponens* is explained amongst Rules of Inference. It is written as:

> $p\rightarrow q\\ p\\∴q$

But $p$ is just a proposition— by definition, it is a statement that is either true or false, but not both. So how can you say that the statement $p$ is true? Does just making some proposition on its own line mean the proposition is true?

**Edit**
Does just making some proposition on its own line mean "if the proposition is true"?

Comment: It is not stated that $p$ is true and also it is not stated that $p$ is false. Actually it is stated that $q$ is true if $p\to q$ and $p$ are both true. Or equivalently that $(p\to q\wedge p)\to q$ is a tautology (i.e. is always true).

Comment: Rules of inference, like *Modus Ponens*, have the property of "preserving truth" (aka : *soundness*) : if the premises are all True, also the conclusion is True.

Comment: @drhab thank you. but i am really want to know is: does saying '$p$" mean "if $q$ is true" ?

Comment: Do you mean in natural language, or in some formal system? In the former case, it is a philosophical question; you would probably be interested in [Tarski's theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth). In the latter case, I suppose the matter is shrouded in technicalities, and you need the services of a logician. IANAL.

Comment: @bof probably this is what i was curious about.

Comment: if you're satisfied with you're answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modus Ponens, as well as other valid argument forms, guarantees the truthfulness of its conclusion (under the assumption that the premises are true), but it does *not* guarantee the truthfulness of its premises. This will become more clear if we review the definition of an argument form and validity.

Modus Ponens is a valid *argument form*, meaning it is an arrangement of variables and operators such that the uniform replacement of the variables by statements results in an argument that is valid. Recall the definition of valid: an argument is valid if and only if it is not possible for the premises of an argument to be true and the conclusion to be false; this implies that **if** the premises are true, **then** the conclusion must also be true.

Thus, Modus Ponens makes no claim about the truthfulness of its premises: $p \rightarrow q$ and $p$. All it means is that "if both premises $p \rightarrow q$ and $p$ are true, then the conclusion $q$ must also be true." In otherwords, $q$ is definitely true ***if*** the premises $p \rightarrow q$ and $p$ are true. If at least one premise is false, then no such guarantee can be made.